# ACF Extended : Disable styles in front

Tags: css

How to disable/remove styles/css in front of the_flexible() function?

I want to load them with vitejs compilation, not from WordPress basic queuing and the_flexible() function.

Do you know how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here my solution:**

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function () {
    // prevent acfe automatic style enqueue
    wp_register_style('titre-sous-le-header-layout-titre-fond-couleur', false);
    wp_register_style('titre-sous-le-header-layout-titre-fond-couleur', false);
    wp_register_script('titre-sous-le-header-layout-titre-fond-couleur', false);
    wp_register_script('titre-sous-le-header-layout-titre-fond-couleur', false);
});
```

## Final Solution

I forgot to show my final solution to eliminate all css load by the_flexible() function:

```
function layout_get($content): void {
    foreach ($content as $layout) {
        foreach ($layout['layouts'] as $value) {
            $handle = acf_slugify($layout['name']) . '-layout-' . acf_slugify($value['name']);
            // prevent acf automatic style enqueue
            wp_register_style($handle, false);
            wp_register_script($handle, false);
        }
    }
}

// Remove style in front only
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function () {
    layout_get(acf_get_fields('group_xxxx'));
});
```